# Implementing Decodable for a wrapper around a fixed size vector

Tags: serialization, rust

Background: the serialize crate is undocumented, deriving Decodable doesn't work. I've also looked at existing implementations for other types and find the code difficult to follow.

How does the decoding process work, and how do I implement Decodable for this struct?

```
pub struct Grid<A> {
    data: [[A,..GRIDW],..GRIDH]
}
```

The reason why `#[deriving(Decodable)]` doesn't work is that `[A,..GRIDW]` doesn't implement Decodable, and it's impossible to implement a trait for a type when both are defined outside of this crate, which is the case here. So the only solution I can see is to manually implement Decodable for Grid.

And this is as far as I've gotten

```
impl <A: Decodable<D, E>, D: Decoder<E>, E> Decodable<D, E> for Grid<A> {
    fn decode(decoder: &mut D) -> Result<Grid<A>, E> {
        decoder.read_struct("Grid", 1u, ref |d| Ok(Grid {
            data: match d.read_struct_field("data", 0u, ref |d| Decodable::decode(d)) {
                Ok(e) => e,
                Err(e) => return Err(e)
            },
        }))
    }
}
```

Which gives an error at `Decodable::decode(d)`

> error: failed to find an implementation of trait
>   serialize::serialize::Decodable for [[A, .. 20], .. 20]

Comment: The simplest way tends to be “change the definition to something that *does* work, get that definition with `--pretty expanded`, and then adjust to suit the new form”.

Comment: @ChrisMorgan I simply don't know how to adjust it to the new form.

Comment: @A.B. what's the JSON string you're trying to deserialise?

Comment: https://github.com/Valve/heliotrope/blob/bdf6294cac3fcb48d08d4f916ca239b9b9e7ea26/src/lib.rs#L132 - a couple of examples of JSON deserialisation

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's not really possible to do this nicely at the moment for a variety of reasons:

- We can't be generic over the length of a fixed length array (the fundamental issue)
- The current trait coherence restrictions means we can't write a custom `trait MyDecodable<D, E> { ... }` with `impl MyDecodable<D, E> for [A, .. GRIDW]` (and one for `GRIDH`) and a blanket implementation `impl<A: Decodable<D, E>> MyDecodable<D, E> for A`. This forces a trait-based solution into using an intermediary type, which then makes the compiler's type inference rather unhappy and AFAICT impossible to satisfy.
- We don't have associated types (aka "output types"), which I think would allow the type inference to be slightly sane.

Thus, for now, we're left with a manual implementation. :(

```
extern crate serialize;

use std::default::Default;
use serialize::{Decoder, Decodable};

static GRIDW: uint = 10;
static GRIDH: uint = 5;


fn decode_grid<E, D: Decoder<E>,
               A: Copy + Default + Decodable<D, E>>(d: &mut D) 
        -> Result<Grid<A>, E> {
    // mirror the Vec implementation: try to read a sequence
    d.read_seq(|d, len| {
        // check it's the required length
        if len != GRIDH {
            return Err(
                d.error(format!("expecting length {} but found {}", 
                                GRIDH, len).as_slice()));
        }
        // create the array with empty values ...
        let mut array: [[A, .. GRIDW], .. GRIDH] 
            = [[Default::default(), .. GRIDW], .. GRIDH];

        // ... and fill it in progressively ...
        for (i, outer) in array.mut_iter().enumerate() {
            // ... by reading each outer element ... 
            try!(d.read_seq_elt(i, |d| {
                //  ... as a sequence ...
                d.read_seq(|d, len| {
                    // ... of the right length,
                    if len != GRIDW { return Err(d.error("...")) }

                    // and then read each element of that sequence as the
                    // elements of the grid.
                    for (j, inner) in outer.mut_iter().enumerate() {
                        *inner = try!(d.read_seq_elt(j, Decodable::decode));
                    }
                    Ok(())
                })
            }));
        }

        // all done successfully!
        Ok(Grid { data: array })
    })
}


pub struct Grid<A> {
    data: [[A,..GRIDW],..GRIDH]
}

impl<E, D: Decoder<E>, A: Copy + Default + Decodable<D, E>> 
    Decodable<D, E> for Grid<A> {
    fn decode(d: &mut D) -> Result<Grid<A>, E> {
        d.read_struct("Grid", 1, |d| {
            d.read_struct_field("data", 0, decode_grid)
        })
    }
}

fn main() {}
```

[playpen](http://play.rust-lang.org/?code=extern%20crate%20serialize%3B%0A%0Ause%20std%3A%3Adefault%3A%3ADefault%3B%0Ause%20serialize%3A%3A%7BDecoder%2C%20Decodable%7D%3B%0A%0Astatic%20GRIDW%3A%20uint%20%3D%2010%3B%0Astatic%20GRIDH%3A%20uint%20%3D%205%3B%0A%0A%0Afn%20decode_grid%3CE%2C%20D%3A%20Decoder%3CE%3E%2C%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20A%3A%20Copy%20%2B%20Default%20%2B%20Decodable%3CD%2C%20E%3E%3E%28d%3A%20%26mut%20D%29%20%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20-%3E%20Result%3CGrid%3CA%3E%2C%20E%3E%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20%2F%2F%20mirror%20the%20Vec%20implementation%3A%20try%20to%20read%20a%20sequence%0A%20%20%20%20d.read_seq%28%7Cd%2C%20len%7C%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%2F%2F%20check%20it%27s%20the%20required%20length%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20if%20len%20!%3D%20GRIDH%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20return%20Err%28%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20d.error%28format!%28%22expecting%20length%20%7B%7D%20but%20found%20%7B%7D%22%2C%20%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20GRIDH%2C%20len%29.as_slice%28%29%29%29%3B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%7D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%2F%2F%20create%20the%20array%20with%20empty%20values%20...%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20let%20mut%20array%3A%20[[A%2C%20..%20GRIDW]%2C%20..%20GRIDH]%20%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%3D%20[[Default%3A%3Adefault%28%29%2C%20..%20GRIDW]%2C%20..%20GRIDH]%3B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%2F%2F%20...%20and%20fill%20it%20in%20progressively%20...%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20for%20%28i%2C%20outer%29%20in%20array.mut_iter%28%29.enumerate%28%29%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%2F%2F%20...%20by%20reading%20each%20outer%20element%20...%20%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20try!%28d.read_seq_elt%28i%2C%20%7Cd%7C%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%2F%2F%20%20...%20as%20a%20sequence%20...%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20d.read_seq%28%7Cd%2C%20len%7C%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%2F%2F%20...%20of%20the%20right%20length%2C%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20if%20len%20!%3D%20GRIDW%20%7B%20return%20Err%28d.error%28%22...%22%29%29%20%7D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%2F%2F%20and%20then%20read%20each%20element%20of%20that%20sequence%20as%20the%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%2F%2F%20elements%20of%20the%20grid.%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20for%20%28j%2C%20inner%29%20in%20outer.mut_iter%28%29.enumerate%28%29%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20*inner%20%3D%20try!%28d.read_seq_elt%28j%2C%20Decodable%3A%3Adecode%29%29%3B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%7D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20Ok%28%28%29%29%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%7D%29%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%7D%29%29%3B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%7D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%2F%2F%20all%20done%20successfully!%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20Ok%28Grid%20%7B%20data%3A%20array%20%7D%29%0A%20%20%20%20%7D%29%0A%7D%0A%0A%0Apub%20struct%20Grid%3CA%3E%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20data%3A%20[[A%2C..GRIDW]%2C..GRIDH]%0A%7D%0A%0Aimpl%3CE%2C%20D%3A%20Decoder%3CE%3E%2C%20A%3A%20Copy%20%2B%20Default%20%2B%20Decodable%3CD%2C%20E%3E%3E%20%0A%20%20%20%20Decodable%3CD%2C%20E%3E%20for%20Grid%3CA%3E%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20fn%20decode%28d%3A%20%26mut%20D%29%20-%3E%20Result%3CGrid%3CA%3E%2C%20E%3E%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20d.read_struct%28%22Grid%22%2C%201%2C%20%7Cd%7C%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20d.read_struct_field%28%22data%22%2C%200%2C%20decode_grid%29%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%7D%29%0A%20%20%20%20%7D%0A%7D%0A%0Afn%20main%28%29%20%7B%7D).

It's also possible to write a more "generic" `[T, .. n]` decoder by using [macros](http://is.gd/UNHcba) to instantiate each version, with special control over how the recursive decoding is handled to allow nested fixed-length arrays to be handled (as required for `Grid`); this requires somewhat less code (especially with more layers, or a variety of different lengths), but the macro solution:

- may be harder to understand, and
- the one I give there may be less efficient (there's a new `array` variable created for every fixed length array, including new `Default`s, while the non-macro solution above just uses a single `array` and thus only calls `Default::default` once for each element in the grid). It may be possible to expand to a similar set of recursive loops, but I'm not sure.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Can this handle JSON? This may be a stupid question, but doesn't JSON require reading the struct name and data field before trying to read the sequence?

Comment: @A.B. Oh, whoops; I had planned for that (why I had a separate function), but forgot to implement it correctly. Fixed now.